# Why is a condition like (0 < a < 5) always true?

Tags: c, boolean, logic

I implemented the following program in C

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main() 
    {
       int a  = 10 ; 
       if(0 < a < 5) 
       {
          printf("The condition is true!") ; 
       }
       return 0 ; 
    }
```

Why does the condition `0<a<5` always return `true`?

Comment: You probably want `0 < a && a < 5` to express the mathematical expression you show here.

Comment: This is a hard bug. There are very few languages which let you do real compound condition things like this.

Comment: @Linuxios: Python specifically is a language that allows you to write range tests like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `0 < a` evaluates to `1`.

Use:

`a > 0 && a < 5`

if you want to test if `a` is greater than `0` and lower than `5`.

Answer (score 14):

Unlike Python (which has [operator chaining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)), C evaluates the condition as:

```
(0 < a) < 5
```

The result of `(0 < a)` is either 0 or 1, both of which are less than 5, so the overall condition is true.

In C, a range test must be written:

```
0 < a && a < 5
```

Note that the Python script:

```
for a in range(-1,7):
  if 0 < a < 5:
    print a, " in range"
  else:
    print a, " out of range"
```

produces the output:

```
-1  out of range
0  out of range
1  in range
2  in range
3  in range
4  in range
5  out of range
6  out of range
```

The 'equivalent' C program using the same `if` condition would, of course, produce the answer 'in range' for each value.

Answer (score 0):

Since `0` is less than `10`, `0 < a` would always evaluates to `1` , which is less than `5`, making `0 < a < 5` always `true`. Change your condition to

```
if(0 < a && a < 5) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if(x<y<z)
```

It actually is valid syntax, but it doesn't do what you want.

Realize that `x<y` returns a bool, i.e. true or false. You then compare it
    against whatever value "z" has. So the intention of "`x<y<z`" looks wrong.

It can be:

```
if(x < y && y < z)
```

Comment: Copied without attrubtion from http://www.mofeel.net/1094-comp-lang-c++/2999.aspx or from http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/805129-can-you-do-if-x-y-z-fctn1

Comment: So somebody wrote in 2008 the *exact same words* that you came up with, completely independently, in 2013? Are you serious?

Comment: @Pekka웃: tell me if it is a complete copy paste..!! i didn't use the link you provided..!! i do refer to links before posting answers..!! sometimes we must borrow some sentences from others..!! but the answer must be relevant to the question..!!