# figuring out integer comparison in C

Tags: c

I'm just wondering how does boundary checking works in the following case.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
                printf("%d < %d < %d is %d\n", i, x, j, i < x < j);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried right-to-left/left-to-right precedence but it doesn't seem to work. (not too sure about it though, maybe it does?)

I think this is undefined behaviour and using && would probably be easier than figuring this out but I'm quite interested in how the logic behind this works. Would appreciate if anyone could help explain this or point me towards the right direction

edit: Thanks for all the help! got the answer I needed. This must seem completely trivial to all of you but it really made many things I thought about in the past few days clicked. Really appreciate the time you guys took to help me out. Thanks again!

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence says it's left to right

Comment: isn't the title misleading?  what does integer boundaries have to do with this?

Comment: I read it as "how do you check if an integer x is between i and j".

Comment: `printf("%d < %d < %d is %d\n", i, x, j, (i < x)&&(x < j));`

Comment: apologies for the misleading title! I'm quite new to this, so I really have no ideas what terminology to use. The title seems like a good choice for me at that time. Perhaps you could clarify the proper context to use integers boundaries? I would really appreciate the help so I wouldn not commit the same mistake again. Anyways, no idea how to change it now. Couldn't find anywhere to edit the title. Sorry!

Comment: found out where to edit the title. didn't really notice the edit button earlier.

Comment: on the topic, am i right to say that integer boundaries meant the maximum and minimum value an integer type can store? from what I've read, this is a concern due to buffer overflow/underflow. was wondering if you could perhaps suggest other problems where integer boundaries are involved in? it sure seemed like an interesting topic!

Comment: Note:  Precede your comments with @user_id to alert a particular user.  "integer boundaries meant the maximum and minimum value an integer type can store" sounds reasonable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is a condition like (0 < a < 5) always true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907265/why-is-a-condition-like-0-a-5-always-true)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i < x < j` is perfectly well-defined, but it doesn't do what you think it does.

It's equivalent to `(i < x) < j`, due to the *associativity* of `<`.

But `(i < x)` is either 0 or 1, as that's how the *relational* operators are defined in C.

So, for example, if `j` is greater than 1, then `i < x < j` is always 1.

Consider writing `i < x && x < j` instead.